# Reloading the "php" tab thread still shows a question no longer tagged as "php"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, question-lists

I removed the "php" tag in an edit for this question [A Database Error Occurred Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41877536/1415724) since there was no php code for it.

When I reloaded the thread page with the "php" tab as being active, the question still showed up in the (php) thread.

Screencap:

[image]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @BhargavRao Sure but the funny thing is, it never did that for me before. I shouldn't have to do a hard refresh CTRL-F5.

Comment: I have experienced that many times before (tagging python-2.7 questions with python, wasn't reflected when I refreshed the page). But usually it works after a few mins. (Not a bug, imo)

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok, thanks. As I said; I do see edited questions with tags that were removed and they do disappear even within a minute (or less). I guess it's how busy the network could be. If you would like to edit the tag for the question as you see fit, it would be good.

Comment: Nah, @Fred-ii-, I'd rather prefer animuson adding a [status-by-design] tag there. That would help us point others with the same issue to this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lists are cached. It's tough to generate a huge multi-hundred page list of questions, so the entire list is just... saved for a while (usually a very short while). It grabs the section of the list that corresponds to that page, and *only* loads all the questions in that section, rather than generating a new list of questions every single time someone loads the page.

So if you make a change, the changes will appear live wherever that question appears. However, if you removed the tag, it can take up to a few minutes for the question to actually disappear from the tag's list, as you need to wait for the list cache to refresh and remove that question from it.

Comment: *"it can take up to a few minutes for the question to actually disappear from the tag's list"* - Ah, I see. Well, I do this every once in a while and do pay close attention to my actions. I'll take your word for it though, thanks. *Cheers*